# Java Web Service under Glassfish 3.0.1 not inserting Chinese characters into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, glassfish-3, cjk

I created a web service using NetBeans 6.9.1 running on the Mac OS under Glassfish 3.0.1 app server. It's method takes a String arg of Chinese characters. It inserts the String into a MySQL database table. When stepping through the server code in debug mode, the characters arrive correctly. A debugger watch shows the query parameter below having the Chinese characters.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(QueryInsertWord);
query.setParameter(1, word);
query.executeUpdate();
```

HOWEVER, upon insert, the database table column has ??? instead of the Chinese characters. I assume the MySQL database is UTF-8 compliant because I can successfully manually cut and paste Chinese characters into that very same column using the Navicat database management tool.

The PU looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>javaapplication1.Registration</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I configured ALL Glassfish jdbc connection pools with the additional properties `useUnicode=true` and `characterEncoding=utf8`.

Please help me.

Comment: Upon configuring the instance of MySQL, did you select "Multi Language Support"? By default, when you configure the MySQL Server instance, the language support used is Latin-1

Comment: Is this when I first create the database? I just checked the database properties in Navicat and my database default characterset is utf8 and default collation is utf8_bin

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in at least two places:

- your connection is not using utf-8. Try passing `characterEncoding=utf8` with the connection string
- your web service is not accepting UTF-8 (for what to do here you have to provide more information)

Also make sure your database is `utf_general_ci` (or similar)

Comment: My connection info via Navicat indicates utf-8:

Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)
Enable MySQL Charset Set: YES
Use Compression: NO
Protocol: 10

Comment: I added the parameter you suggested as follows: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myserver?characterEncoding=utf8 but no success.

Comment: Also, my database default characterset is utf8 and default collation is utf8_bin

Comment: What additional info can I provide that would be helpful?

Comment: @user273565 your web service configurations. But before you do that, check what does `request.getCharaceterEncoding()` return (you should be able to get the request somehow, depending on the web service stack)

Comment: I am a bit of a newbee. Where is this request object to which you refer? Am I checking within the web service method? Is my web service configurations in the sun-web.xml or are you referring to Glassfish configuration info?

Comment: @user273565 I can't recall well, there was something like MessageContext via which you could obtain the request. Google around :)

Comment: I have been googling around and this seems to relate more to get/post type stuff and not a web service call per say. I think the problem is either at the Glassfish connection pool or the EntityManager in my server code off of which I create the query.

Comment: @user273565 put a `Filter` in front of the web service handling servler (there should be one), and inspect the request there

Comment: Thank you. I am working on that now. However, since the debugger shows me that the String argument within the web service method has the correct encoding, isn't this test unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The character encoding of the web service is indeed UTF-8. The MySQL database is also UTF-8. The problem SEEMS to have been in the persistence unit which uses the Eclipse JPA 2.0 library. I suspect this because when I composed the native query with the parameter in question as a byte[] as opposed to a string, the correct characters were persisted in the database. In summary, I now pass the expression "data.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))" to the query parameter object, as opposed to the string "data". Since the data is indeed in UTF-8, the getBytes call interprets the byte array correctly. The overloaded parameter object passes the byte array to the entity manager and its persistence library before it finally reaches the MySQL database. The MySQL database is UTF-8 with a column of type LongText. The bytes are then inserted correctly into that column. Please feel free to comment further if anyone feels that I am assuming anything incorrectly. I needed to move on with the project and, therefore, am not delving into the matter further at this particular time. Thank you all for your help, especially Bozho who put me looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,
Append the query string to jdbc url

```
&characterEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=utf8
```

At the end should show as this:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASE_NAME?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;characterSetResults=utf8"/>
```